# Exclude certain references in the bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm creating my bib-file (`Literaturverzeichnis.bib`) with jabref under windows and I'm also inserting papers and books etc which I read but might not need as they might be irrelevant for my current work. But I still want to keep them in the bib-file to always have a record of what I've read already (taking notes on each entry with a short summary on my own if the entry is relevant or not).

I therefore organize the entries in groups, one group called `_irrelevant_`.
Then I insert them into my thesis via

```
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}    % Literaturverzeichnis nach DIN 1505
\bibliography{Literaturverzeichnis}
```

Would it be now possible to somehow exclude

either

- a) every entry of my reference-list which wasn't quoted in my thesis at all by using `\cite{XYZ`}

or

- b) (if a) isn't possible) only display entries of certain groups (so that I could exclude all entries which I assigned to group `_irrelevant_` and only display the relevant entries)

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Just don't use `\nocite{*}`. In this case only quoted entries are listed in the bibliography.

Comment: Oh okay, didn't see in the template that there was yet another command interfering into the bibliographics-behaviour. Thank you a lot. If you write a whole answer, I'll accept it, because you solved it via a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess somewhere in you template the command `\nocite{*}` is used. This leads to a bibliography where all entries of the bibliography file are printed. So comment out the command `\nocite{*}`. In this case only quoted entries are listed in the bibliography.